# Defining Project Paths in a Solution via Macro/Environment Variable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, environment-variables, projects-and-solutions

Is there a way to define the project file path in a solution using a user macro/environment variable? I can't seem to do that.

Kind of like an environment variable is used to define the additional include directories in a C++ project, except I want to do the same for the location of a project file in a solution.

I've tried editing the solution in a text editor to change the path to start with %MyMacroName% or $(MyMacroName) but neither of them seems to parse just right. The project files can't be located when the solution is opened.

Comment: Did you restart Visual Studio after setting environment variable?

Comment: I closed the solution and reopened it. I was mostly trying to do this as a user macro in a property sheet, but if it must be an environment variable, that's fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In .sln file use syntax "%ENV_VAR%rest_of_the_path\test.csproj"

In .csproj file use syntax "$(ENV_VAR)rest_of_the_path\test.dll"

That works for me, ENV_VAR is custom environment variable defined for operating system like ENV_VAR = "C:\MyPath\"

Comment: Settled for using an environment variable over a user macro so that the syntax would work.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for files included directly in solution folders

Comment: Be aware that introducing variables into a .sln file means that they cannot be used with MSBuild.  See See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/690318/msbuild-doesnt-parse-environment-variables-in-sln-files

Comment: @cowlinator which version of MSBuild did you try?

Comment: MSBuild 15.4.8.50001 (installed from Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 15.4.5) among others.  Have you tried building a .sln file containing %environment_variables% with MSBuild?

Comment: I did some time ago, but not with VS2017 for sure.

Answer (score 1):

MSBuild allows you use to environment variables,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms171459(v=VS.80).aspx

So that you should be able to define environment variables as you wish, and then modify vCxproj files to make use of them.

I am not sure if that tip works for sln files, as sln files are not MSBuild scripts.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft Docs [.vcxproj and .props file structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcxproj-file-structure?view=msvc-170):

> We recommend you only create and modify .vcxproj projects in the IDE, and avoid manual editing as much as possible. In most cases, you never need to manually edit the project file. Whenever possible you should use the Visual Studio property pages to modify project settings.

> If you need customizations that aren't possible in the IDE, we recommend you add custom **props** or **targets**.

In **props** file, use syntax `<ENV_VAR>your_local_path</ENV_VAR>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
    <ENV_VAR>your_local_path</ENV_VAR>
```