# MSbuild doesn't expand environment variables

Tags: msbuild

I'm using MSBuild to build a solution file from the command line. In it, the path to the vcxproj file is specified by an environment variable FOO by %FOO%\ProjName.vcxproj

When I open the sln in the IDE, I the project is found and loaded. When I use msbuild from the command line (on the same machine) I get an error of:

```
The Project File "C:\Blah\Blah\%FOO%\ProjName.vcxproj" was not found,
```

In the same command prompt

```
echo %FOO%
```

Gives me the correctly expanded path.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/690318/msbuild-doesnt-parse-environment-variables-in-sln-files

Comment: Based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669000/defining-project-paths-in-a-solution-via-macro-environment-variable) (and my own implementation) MSBuild uses the $(Foo) syntax in the project files, yet SLN files use %FOO%

Comment: see edited comment :]

Comment: Marked as wontfix, great. No explanation as to how you might work around it either. Guess I'll end up copying the sln file, replacing %FOO% with the path, and writing it back out again. bleh.

Comment: Indeed it's a pitty. Guess we'll have to wait until they (finally) make solutions msbuild files as well. As far as I know it is definitely on the roadmap.

Comment: Since the connect.microsoft.com site is now defunct, I have opened a new bug at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/248631/msbuild-doesnt-parse-environment-variables-in-sln.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments; this is a known bug and a wontfix from MS. I ended up writing a batch file to copy the sln file and expand the environment variables, build that, and delete the new sln. Works fine.

Comment: Would you care to share the batch code you have written?

Answer (score 0):

As @maccard stated, this is a known bug.  (See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/248631/msbuild-doesnt-parse-environment-variables-in-sln.html and https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/120 )

You can use the following script to replace all environment variables in a .sln file with their values.  (Script is only very lightly tested).

```
# Python 2.7
# usage: python fix_sln.py path/to/file.sln


import codecs
import os
import re
import shutil
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with codecs.open(sys.argv[1], encoding='utf-8-sig') as orig:
        with codecs.open(sys.argv[1] + '.modified', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as new:
            for line in orig:
                line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
                found = re.search(r"""%.+%""", line)
                line = line.replace(str(found.group()), os.environ.get(str(found.group()).replace("""%""", ""))) if found else line
                new.write(line + '\r\n')
    shutil.move(sys.argv[1] + '.modified', sys.argv[1])
```