# Project paths in a Visual Studio Solution via Environment Variable and msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I use syntax like "**%SDK_PATH%**\sdk_dir\test.vcxproj" in **.sln** file. 
And it is work fine for me from IDE.

But msbuildl does not understand this syntax and will emit a error MSB3202 ("The project file was not found.") when I use it from command line:

> msbuild test.sln /p:Configuration=Debug

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803442/msbuild-doesnt-expand-environment-variables